# Provisioning profiles under xcode account not showing.

Tags: ios, xamarin, mobile, provisioning-profile

I have created and installed 3 ios certificates which now show under xcode - preferences - account.

I have succesfully created an ios device,

I used the 2 above and an App ID and created a provisioning profile in Developer Console.

When I download it and open in my mac, it does not appear in Xcode Account Certificates.

Things ive tried with no luck:

I pressed "Download manual profiles"

double clicked the downloaded .mobileprovision files.

created 3 different provision profiles in case i did something wrong.

Under Window - Devices in xclode i can see the provisioning profiles are installed on the device..

Anything im missing? Ive been trying to get this to work for 2 weeks now with no luck

Thank u in advance!

Antonis

Comment: please make sure that the  provisioning profile and the certificates match the build configuration .

Comment: Please go to finder and find this "~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles". If this is contains any file then it means your profile is installed on your mac.